# Req files undefined express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, google-cloud-functions

I am creating Endpoint that can be used to  insert video into the GCP storage bucket, Actually its working in a POC separate script file when I'm tried to integrate with project Couldn't get file via postman its undefined
Here I posted my POC code as well as my project code

```
const express = require('express')
const upload = require('express-fileupload')
const uuid = require('uuid-v4');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccount")
const app = express()


app.use(upload(
  {
    limits: { fileSize: 500 * 1024 * 1024 },
  },
  {
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : '/tempFolder/'
}));

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "BcketPath"
});


const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();


// app.get('/', (req,res) => {
//     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
// })

app.post('/upload',async (req,res) => {
    console.log(req)
    console.log("req.files",req.files)
    if(req.files) {
        console.log(req.files)
        for (let key in req.files) {
                console.log("-------------------",req.files[key].name);
                console.log( req.files[key])
                let file = req.files[key]
                const filename = file.name
                console.log(filename)

                file.mv('/tempFolder/'+filename, function(err){
                    if(err) {
                        res.send(err)
                    }
                })
                
                const metadata = {
                metadata: {
                    firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
                },
                contentType: 'video/mp4',
                cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
                };
            
                const store = await bucket.upload('/tempFolder/'+filename, {
                gzip: false,
                metadata: metadata,
                });
               
                if (store.err) { console.log('error');}
                else { console.log('fetched response'+store);}

                console.log(store)
                console.log(`${filename} uploaded.`);
        }

        res.status(200).send({ status: 'success' });
   }
})

app.listen(7000, () => {
    console.log(`  Server ready at http://localhost:7000/`);
  });
```

My project code

```
'use strict';

const upload = require('express-fileupload')
const uuid = require('uuid-v4');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const SCHEMA = require('./schema');
const time = require('date-and-time');
const CONSTANTS = require('./../../../constants');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
 
module.exports = (app) => {

    const recordings = app.db.firestore.collection('recordings');
    app.use(upload(
        {
          useTempFiles : true,
          tempFileDir : '/temp/'
      }
     ));   
       const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
      
    //---------------uploadFile starts, Here we are storing video to the storage bucket------------------------//

    const uploadFile = async (req,res) => {  
      try {
          console.log(req.files)    
          const user_name = "user"
          if(req.files) {
              for (let key in req.files) {             
                      let file = req.files[key]
                      //const filename = file.name  
                      const filename = await uuid(`${Date.now() + file.name }`)
                      console.log(videoname)
                      file.mv('/temp/'+filename, (err)=> {
                          if(err) {
                           return Promise.reject(err);
                          }})                    
                      const metadata = {
                      metadata: {
                          firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
                      },
                      contentType: 'video/mp4',
                      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
                      };        
                      const uploadedVideo = await bucket.upload(filename, {
                      destination: CONSTANTS.VIDEO_DESTINATION+user_name+'/'+filename,
                      gzip: false,
                      metadata: metadata,
                      });    
                      if (uploadedVideo.err) { console.log('error');}
                      else { console.log('fetched response'+uploadedVideo);}
                      console.log(uploadedVideo[0].metadata)
                      const videoPath = uploadedVideo[0].metadata.name

              }     
              return Promise.resolve({ content: "success" });       
            }
            else {
                return Promise.reject({ content: "There are no files" });
            }
            
    }
  
    catch (e) {
        const res = {
            errCode: 'UNKNOWN_ERROR',
            errDetails: 'Unable to upload Videos',
            statusCode: 400
        };
        console.log(e);
        return Promise.reject(res)
    }
}

    return { uploadFile: uploadFile, getFile:getFile };
};
```

And I am not sure where should I need to add the  following one
`app.use(upload({ useTempFiles : true,tempFileDir : '/tempFolder/' }));` 
And i added these lines also

`
//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());
`

Comment: If `req.files` is undefined, it's not passing through the `express-fileupload` middleware. What is the `app` argument that you're passing to the `uploadFile` function?

Comment: that one I created temp folder, where I can store the videos then  can upload to the bucket